# Place a dot above and to left of binary operator

Tags: math-operators, accents

How can one place a dot above and to the left of a binary operator?

I know that to place a dot above a binary operator I can do this:

```
\dot{\sqsubseteq}
```

but this places the dot nicely above the centre of the operator.

I had a go at this (stabbing in the dark!):

```
\ldot {\sqsubseteq}
```

thinking that it might mean "left dot above", but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

This might suit your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ldot[1]{\mathpalette\@ldot{#1}}
\newcommand\@ldot[2]{%
  \binrel@{#2}\binrel@@{%
    \ooalign{%
      $\m@th#1#2$\cr
      $\m@th#1\dot{\vphantom{#1#2}}$\hidewidth\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[a \ldot{\subseteq} b\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Stack it!  Here given as `\dotbin{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\dotbin[1]{%
  \mathbin{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{1pt}{\,#1}{.}{O}{l}{F}{F}{S}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
A \sqsubseteq B \dotbin{\sqsubseteq} C
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need it at smaller math sizes, let me know and I will supplement the answer.

Comment: `\sqsubseteq` is `\mathrel`

Comment: @egreg I was just trying to follow the OP's wishes, where both "binary operator" and `\sqsubseteq` were mentioned in the same sentence.  Obviously, it is incumbent on the OP to use `\dotbin` in the manner in which it is intended.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\ldotsqsubseteq}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mspace{2.5mu}%
    \dot{\vphantom{\sqsubseteq}}%
    \mspace{-2.5mu}%
  }%
  \sqsubseteq
}

\begin{document}

$A \ldotsqsubseteq B$

$A \sqsubseteq B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: request was for the dot "to the left", not "above on the left".  (possibly ambiguous.)

Comment: The OP added “left dot above”.

Answer (score 1):

on the assumption that you really do want the dot to the left of the `\subseteq`, this should do it.  obviously, the expression shown is nonsense, but should serve to demonstrate that the size varies appropriately with position, without resorting to `\mathpalette` or other explicit sizing techniques.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dotsseq}{\mathrel{\dot{\vphantom{t}}{\subseteq}}}

\begin{document}
\[ a \dotsseq b \int_{c\dotsseq e} x \]
\end{document}
```

[image]